# sql preferred selection type?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
  SELECT a=1,b=2
vs
  SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b
```

[image]

what approach should i use ? (by best practice decisions)

Is there any advantages of one vs the other ?

Comment: The differences are purely syntactic (which is another way of saying "there is no real difference").

Comment: The second one is `ANSI` the first one isn't so if portability is a concern that might be relevant.

Comment: @MartinSmith , thanks an important part indeed. but what benefit am i gaining from it being ANSI ? thanks :)

Comment: Aaron Bertrand recently posted an article on the SQL Blog about this: https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I use `AS` - it is more explicit and used elsewhere (table aliases).

It is also standard - using the `=` syntax will not work on some databases.

I don't believe there are any performance implications for using one over the other.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think where is a difference. But i would prefer the second approach. I think its more logical than the first.

So, i use the  `AS` approach.

> **AS** temporarily assigns a table column a new name. This grants the SQL developer the ability to make adjustments to the presentation of query results and allow the developer to label results more accurately without permanently renaming table columns. [Source](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlas.php)

Answer (score 0):

I use `AS`. It's a more `SQL` friendly way!

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b`

is common for all DBs